# Is there a way to add an object to spring's persistence context without retrieving it from the database?

Tags: spring, hibernate

Say I have the following entity classes:

```
    public class childClass {
    
    @Id
    private Long Id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private ParentClass parentClass;

public ChildClass(ParentClass parentClass){
  this.parentClass = parentClass;
}
    
    //other fields
    }

public class ParentClass{

@Id
private Long id;

public ParentClass(Long id){
   this.id = id;
}

}
```

I want to persist a group of new `ChildClass` objects based on a `Set` of `ParentClass` ids. Ideally i would like to do that like this:

```
parentClassSet.stream().map(parentId -> new ChildClass(new ParentClass(parentId)).collect(Collectors.toList());
childClassDao.save(parentClassSet);
```

But this will throw an error because the `ParentClass` objects do not exist in the persistence context and thus spring does not recognize these objects as valid `entities`.

I have to retrieve the ParentClass from the database first, based on an id and then use that object to createt a new ChildClass object with. My question is: If i already know that a ParentClass object with an id exists in the database, is it possible to create a ParentClass with that id and tell Spring to treat it as a valid `entity`?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EntityManager has a getReference() method for that purpose.

> **getReference**
>
> T getReference(Class entityClass,
> Object primaryKey)
>
> Get an instance, whose state may be lazily fetched. If the requested
> instance does not exist in the database, the EntityNotFoundException
> is thrown when the instance state is first accessed. (The persistence
> provider runtime is permitted to throw the EntityNotFoundException
> when getReference is called.) The application should not expect that
> the instance state will be available upon detachment, unless it was
> accessed by the application while the entity manager was open.
>
> Parameters: entityClass - entity class primaryKey - primary key
>
> Returns: the found entity instance
>
> Throws: IllegalArgumentException - if the first argument does not
> denote an entity type or the second argument is not a valid type for
> that entity's primary key or is null EntityNotFoundException - if the
> entity state cannot be accessed

Comment: For those using Spring data (like me). You can achieve the same with the `getOne(id)` method of `JpaRepository` because it uses entityManager.getReference() under the hood